# How do I name keys in a Hashtable differently

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I want to do Breadth first search algorithm as a maze solver. The maze is made out of a TableLayoutPanel.

I have something like this:

```
  Hashtable hash = new Hashtable();
  Queue<TableLayoutPanelCellPosition> q_cellposition = new Queue<TableLayoutPanelCellPosition>();
  while (q_cellposition.Count != 0)
        {
            TableLayoutPanelCellPosition currentPosition = q_cellposition.Dequeue();
            TableLayoutPanelCellPosition left = new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(currentPosition.Column - 1, currentPosition.Row);
            Label leftN = (Label)tlp.GetControlFromPosition(left.Column, left.Row);
            TableLayoutPanelCellPosition right = new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(currentPosition.Column + 1, currentPosition.Row);
            Label rightN = (Label)tlp.GetControlFromPosition(right.Column, right.Row);

            hash.Add(leftN, currentPosition);
            q_cellposition.Enqueue(left);

            hash.Add(rightN, currentPosition);
            q_cellposition.Enqueue(right);
        }
```

Now, after the first iteration, it obviously tries to add the new KeyValuePair to the Hashtable. However, it sees the new leftN key and rightN key as the same Label (even though they technically are not) and it throws me the error that the the key is already added. I guess I have to change the name of the key everytime I add something to the Hashtable. My question is now: How do I do that, efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

[I believe that some consider the Hashtable obsolete](https://www.dotnetperls.com/hashtable) or inferior to the generic [`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) object, you should probably use that.

[I think you might be able to use the array operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.item(v=vs.110).aspx) to access and replace a key that's already in a `Dictionary` or `Hashtable` without it throwing an exception for that key already being present.

[`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.add(v=vs.110).aspx) is more for when you know the key is not yet in the `Hashtable`.

So the `Add` statements would change from:

```
hash.Add(leftN, currentPosition);
```

to

```
hash[leftN] = currentPosition;
```

Unless you need to create unique keys for each item even if they share the same key.  At that point though you might switch to a key generation method that makes those same keys different by adding in another variable during key generation or you need to switch to another more appropriate data structure.

If your keys are always hitting you might say separate the left and right into two different hash tables, though I doubt that's what you want.   Or you can add a prefix with the current iteration onto the front of the key.  But at that point you are probably better off with a generic [`Stack` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx).